# UAC Whitelist for system processes?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, uac

On my computer (I am running Windows 7 Home Premium on an Administrator account), I have noticed that programs such as Resource Monitor, Task Manager, and MMC snap-ins do not prompt for UAC permission to start even when starting them with elevated permission, making it look like there is a UAC whitelist for certain system processes (there is obviously no Scheduled Tasks entry for them). How do these processes do this, and if there is a whitelist, where is it?

Comment: The whitelist is baked into Windows itself.  There's no known way to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitelist is part of [Windows and only works for Microsoft tools which are signed by Microsoft, reside in a "secure directory", and have this entry in the Manifest file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx#id0560031):

[image]

So you can't modify this.

Comment: Not only signed by Microsoft, but signed by the special "Windows publisher" certificate from Microsoft which is only used for core windows components.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks the additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I will mark this as the accepted answer, but an extreme solution (not advisable for any except malware writers) can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx#id0560040).